# Removing shadow and add Tracking in video OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv

[image: Previous output]

Above is the output I've got from my code, however there is a significant amount of shadows in the image, is there any ways that I can do to remove shadows? And also add object tracking that create box for moving car? Thank you so much

```
//create Background Subtractor objects
Ptr < BackgroundSubtractor > pBackSub;
if (parser.get <String>("algo") == "MOG2")
    pBackSub = createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
VideoCapture capture(parser.get <String>("input")); //input video
Mat frame, fgMask;
while (true) {
    capture >> frame;
    if (frame.empty()) //break if frame empty
        break;
    //update the background model
    pBackSub - > apply(frame, fgMask);
    //erode the frame with 3x3 kernel
    Mat frame_eroded_with_3x3_kernel;
    erode(fgMask, frame_eroded_with_3x3_kernel, getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(3, 3)));
    //dilate the frame with 2x2 kernel
    Mat frame_dilate_with_2x2_kernel;
    dilate(frame_eroded_with_3x3_kernel, frame_dilate_with_2x2_kernel, getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(2, 2)));
    //show the current frame and the fg mask
    imshow("Frame", frame);
    imshow("FG Mask", fgMask);
    imshow("After eroded with 3x3 kernel", frame_eroded_with_3x3_kernel);
    imshow("After dilate with 2x2 kernel", frame_dilate_with_2x2_kernel);
    //get the input from the keyboard
    int keyboard = waitKey(30);
    if (keyboard == 'q' || keyboard == 27)
        break;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this will help but is it possible to post a screen shot of the problem?

Comment: The screenshot is in the post, I'm unable to post a photo but here's the link [link]https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7qqp.png , thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your output is correct. The first do not use moving camera video. Scene needs to be stable as well with good light conditions.  You can try different parameters of MOG2 setting. History influence how previous frames influence the current. varThreshold can significantly help you. detectShadows=false is better, You can try false and true to see the difference. You can remove detected shadow, but the methods have the limitations.

```
cv::createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2 (int history=500, double varThreshold=16, bool detectShadows=true)
```

You can enhance the output by using additional filtering and morphological operations for example in case of noise are useful. Search for the information about the following two functions and try them to apply.

```
cv::dilate
cv::erode
```

The point is simple. Do not expect the miracle. This is not suitable for many task in computer vision. 
The detection and other task are not based on background subtraction in most of the application. In the following image the background subtraction failing due to the car lights changing conditions and shadows.
[image: Car detection]

The detection is based on features that represent car instead of detect what is not a background. This is better way for most of the application. Haar, LBP detection or deeplearning. You can find many tutorials for detection on my page [funvision](https://funvision.blogspot.com/)

Comment: I already tried this however the image is still filled with shadows, do I need a separate function to remove the shadow?

Comment: Just note that bool detectShadows=true will not remove shadow, just detect the shadow for you. and the method is not able to deal with the bad light conditions at all. I think the better is consider the different approach than detect based on background segmentation.

Comment: thank you, however is there any method that I can add box around moving cars?

Comment: Yes, for exaple haar lbp or other modern detector. I have tutorial for car detection, there is lbp cascade to download, code sample and video example https://funvision.blogspot.com/2016/12/lbp-cascade-for-car-detection-in-opencv.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

I think the [erosion function in opencv](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html) should be able to solve the issue. This function uses a rectangular structuring element of size 3x3 to remove the white dots . I think the size of the element can be given as parameters.

Use fgMask  as erosion input.